# Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I carefully read the threads about this error. None of the proposed solutions (truncate /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available or changing from https to http in /etc/update-manager/meta-release) worked for me.

```
[xavier@imladris ~]$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
Upgrades to the development release are only
available from the latest supported release.
```

My network is OK, I can even see the meta-release file in a browser.

Fun fact, it worked yesterday, but I had no time for the upgrade. Furthermore, it worked on n Ubuntu VM I have on a BHve host on the very same network

So it seems to be a transient error. Is there a way to fix it permanently ?

FYI, my motd :

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-33-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 updates can be applied immediately.
```

Thanks, regards,

Xavier

EDIT : I've activated debug mode, an I get

```
[xavier@imladris ~]$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d -e DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER=1
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
MetaRelease.__init__() useDevel=True useProposed=False
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: -development
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: -proposed
metarelease-uri: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development
MetaRelease.download()
result of meta-release download: '<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>'
Failed to connect to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
NO self.metarelease_information
Upgrades to the development release are only
available from the latest supported release.
[xavier@imladris ~]$ sudo geany /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py
[xavier@imladris ~]$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d -e DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER=1
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
MetaRelease.__init__() useDevel=True useProposed=False
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: -development
/etc/update-manager/meta-release: -proposed
metarelease-uri: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development
MetaRelease.download()
result of meta-release download: '<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>'
Failed to connect to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
NO self.metarelease_information
Upgrades to the development release are only
available from the latest supported release.
```

A DNS problem ?
I put changelogs.ubuntu.com in /etc/hosts file with no success

Comment: Can you please add the content of your `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` file ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. How did you solve this problem?

Comment: It was actually a transient DNS error, caused by resolvect

Comment: I have similar problem. I try some tests on windows machine in same network: Url in browser works, in powershell using Invoke-WebRequest works, in git bash curl on same machine didnt work. But what is interesting - in chrome dev tools i have totally different IP address.

Comment: This happened to me after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. I don't have a permanent solution yet. I tried restarting resolved via systemctl and now DNS works, but the banner still shows that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on one Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 this problem was caused by config of `APT Proxy server` (probably proxy server doesn't have some SSL Root CA or other problem).

After comenting out Proxy config in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` the upgrade of my Ubuntu servers starts without problems.